# How to confirm I'm connected with WPA3 (on Linux Mint 20.2)?

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi, wpa-supplicant, wpa3

In my TP-Link router, I have set WPA version 2/3:

[image: router WPA 2&3]

I am on Linux Mint 20.2 and I have explicitly set WPA3 for my connection:

[image: mint WPA 3 explicit]

---

```
sudo wpa_cli status wlp60s0
```

outputs:

```
Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlp60s0'
wpa_state=DISCONNECTED
...
```

and

```
sudo iwlist wlp60s0 scanning
```

outputs:

```
wlp60s0   Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: [mac-censored]
                    Channel:48
                    Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
                    Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"[ssid-censored]"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000009e5fb8041
                    Extra: Last beacon: 652ms ago
                    ...
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (2) : PSK unknown (8)
```

Question:

I am testing WPA3, so far only [Steam has had some crashes due to WPA3](https://store.steampowered.com/oldnews/86266) that I know of, a quote:

> ... Fixed crashes when on a WPA3 wireless network ...

**How to confirm I'm connected with WPA3 (on Linux Mint 20.2)?**

---

The furthest I managed to get was to verify the connected (as for searching for `yes`) network is WPA3-capable or more precisely WPA2/WPA3 as set in the router using `nmcli`:

```
sudo nmcli -f all -s dev wifi | grep -e yes -e SSID
```

which outputs:

```
NAME   SSID                SSID-HEX                              BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   WPA-FLAGS                 RSN-FLAGS                     DEVICE   ACTIVE  IN-USE  DBUS-PATH                                      
AP[2]  [censored]          [censored]                            [censored]         Infra  48    5240 MHz  270 Mbit/s  79      ▂▄▆_  WPA2 WPA3  (none)                    pair_ccmp group_ccmp psk sae  wlp60s0  yes     *       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command did select a wrong interface. Run the `sudo wpa_cli -i wlp60s0 status` command to get the correct interface.

Here is my output with `wlan0` selected by default, so I did not need to explicitly set it.

```
$ wpa_cli status
Selected interface 'wlan0'
bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
freq=2462
ssid=My Cool WiFi AP
id=0
mode=station
pairwise_cipher=CCMP
group_cipher=CCMP
key_mgmt=SAE
pmf=1
mgmt_group_cipher=BIP
sae_group=19
wpa_state=COMPLETED
ip_address=X.X.X.X
```

`key_mgmt=SAE` `pmf=1` **`sae_group=19`** `wpa_state=COMPLETED` indicate that you are using WPA3.

This will work for `wpa_supplicant`.

With `iwd`, use `iwctl station`:

```
sudo iwctl station wlan0 show | grep Security
```

will show the security setting for the network you are connected to. Use `iwctl station list` to find the name of the interface currently in use.

In my case with wpa3-sae:
Security            WPA3-Personal

Answer (score 3):

Artem's answer is almost correct, but you need to specify the `-i` option for `wpa_cli`.

`sudo wpa_cli status wlp60s0` is not the proper syntax. This is from the man page of wpa_cli

```
wpa_cli [-p<path to ctrl sockets>] [-i<ifname>] [-hvB] [-a<action file>] \
        [-P<pid file>] [-g<global ctrl>] [-G<ping interval>] \
        [-s<wpa_client_socket_file_path>] [command..]
```

So what actually gets executed in your case is just `sudo wpa_cli status`. Your wireless card actually has two interfaces that are brought up with `wpa_supplicant` (when it is supported). There is the regular `wlp60s0`, and there is a p2p interface that can run concurrently alongside the main interface called `p2p-dev-wlp60s0`. Your output

```
Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlp60s0'
wpa_state=DISCONNECTED
...
```

shows the interface as disconnected because `wpa_cli` selected the incorrect interface by default. To get the output you're looking for, run

```
sudo wpa_cli -i wlp60s0 status
```

Answer (score 0):

### Observation

Based upon the above answers, I ran:

```
sudo wpa_cli -i wlp60s0 status
```

twice. First when connected via [WPA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access#WPA2), and second when connected via [WPA3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access#WPA3).

---

I stored both of the outputs into text files and with a simple `diff` comparison can be found what identifies WPA3:

```
10c10
< key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
---
> key_mgmt=SAE
12a13
> sae_group=19
```

---

### Conclusion

There is one line different. The `key_mgmt` is equal to `WPA2-PSK` in case of using WPA2 pre-shared key, and `SAE` in case of WPA3 pre-shared key.

And in case of WPA3, there is one more key added, the `sae_group`.